# What's happens with facebook redirection login? SDK 4.0

Tags: php, facebook

Well, I developed anothers apps with last SDK but I don't know what im doing wrong now. I am using this example:

https://gist.github.com/niraj-shah/ab1c74ad83df172e6075

And the problem is with redirection:

`// show login url
$url = $helper->getLoginUrl( array( 'email', 'user_friends'));
echo '<a href="' . $url. '">Login</a>';
echo $url;`

I use echo $url for see if the link was ok, and when I wrote in address bar works perfectly. If I use php header it gives me an server 404 error.

Please help!``